# Apply Multiple CSS classes on an HTML element (jQuery addClass)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Given this HTML:

```
<html>
<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    tr.Class1
    {
      background-color: Blue;
    }
    .Class2
    {
      background-color: Red;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <table>
    <tr id="tr1">
      <td>Row 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr2">
      <td>Row 2</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Below is the script secion. What will happen when I click on the first row? Will it remain blue, or will it turn red? If it will remain blue, how do I get it to turn red instead WITHOUT removing the Class1 class from the row (so I can remove the Class2 class later and the row will return to its original color of blue)?

```
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">

  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("#tr1").addClass("Class1");

    $("tr").click(function() {
      /* clicked tr's should use the Class2 class to indicate selection, but only one should be selected at a time */

      $(".Class2").removeClass("Class2");
      $(this).addClass("Class2");
    });
  });

</script>
```

**Edit**
I should say - I tried this, and it's not working as expected (in either FireFox or IE). What is going on?

Comment: It turns red for me, as expected, given your code above. If it's not working for you, you've got other code or rules interacting that we can't see.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Figured it out. I put my example up a little incorrectly. The CSS actually looked like:

```
tr.Class1
{
  background-color: Blue;
}
.Class2
{
  background-color: Red;
}
```

Therefore, the most specific rule applies, just like Mozilla told me [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Common_CSS_Questions):

> If the same property is declared in
>   both rules, the conflict is resolved
>   first through specificity, then
>   according to the order of the CSS
>   declarations. The order of classes in
>   the class attribute is not relevant.

Answer (score 1):

It should turn red...that's why it's called *cascading* style sheets...new additions to the properties override older ones.

Comment: I know, but I'm not getting that behavior.

Answer (score 1):

Mozilla says [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Common_CSS_Questions):

> If the same property is declared in
>   both rules, the conflict is resolved
>   first through specificity, then
>   according to the order of the CSS
>   declarations. The order of classes in
>   the class attribute is not relevant.

But this isn't the behavior I'm getting.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
 $("tr").click(function() {
  /* clicked tr's should use the Class2 class to indicate selection, but only one  should be selected at a time */

  $(".Class2").removeClass("Class2");
  $(this).toggleClass("Class1");
  $(this).addClass("Class2");
  $(this).toggleClass("Class1");
});
```

I don't know if it will work but maybe it will give you more into the problem.